# SQL query for tree table menu

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with tree structure:

```
ID    Title           ParentID     Orderby 
----------------------------------------
1     All             0            2
2     Banking         1            5
3     USAA Checking   0            0
4     USAA Mastercard 1            9
5     Medical         3            0
6     Jobs            3            100
7     Archive         0            1
8     Active          7            0  
9     BoA Amex        1            1
```

I need to write a SQL query to produce a result like this (ORDER by column Orderby):

```
ID    Title           Path         Orderby 
----------------------------------------
3     USAA Checking   1            0
5     Medical         1.1          0
6     Jobs            3.2          100
7     Archive         2            1
8     Active          2.1          0
1     All             3            2
9     BoA Amex        3.1          1
2     Banking         3.2          5
4     USAA Mastercard 3.3          9
```

Who can help me to write a SQL query? Thanks!

Comment: You should explain your logic

Comment: Consider using [HierarchyID](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference&ved=2ahUKEwjCjIG-84ffAhXLIDQIHS6vCYAQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3-x7eKCHMYa0eJc3ghbCsb)

Comment: Otherwise, you'll need a recursive CTE

Comment: explain how you calculated the path for `USAA Mastercard`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH children AS (
    SELECT NULL AS ParentID, ID, Title, Orderby,
        CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(500)) AS Path
    FROM Categories
    WHERE ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
       d.ParentID, t.counter + 1, d.ID, d.Title, d.Orderby,
       CAST(CAST(t.Path AS VARCHAR(50)) + '.' +
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.ParentID ORDER BY d.ID) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS VARCHAR(500))
    FROM children t
    INNER JOIN Categories AS d
        ON d.ParentID = t.ID
)

SELECT ID, Title, Path, Orderby
FROM children;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that you never provided fixed logic for what should be used to determine the minor version numbers, for a given parent version.  That is, it is not clear why `Medical` appears earlier than `Jobs` in the hierarchy.

Comment: No, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: check again, i just adjust the question to make it easier to understand and sorry because i'm not so good at English

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `row_number()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13de3096a157642d459835486d7a033b)**

```
select Id,title, concat(val,'.',case when 
row_number() over(partition by val order by Id)-1=0 then null else 
row_number() over(partition by val order by Id)-1 end) as path,
orderby
from
(
select *,case when parentid=0 then id else parentid end as val
from Categories
)A
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try  Below query if you have one level of the hierarchy

```
 Select  
      C.ID as ID, 
      C.Title  as Title, 
      Case 
        when C.ParentID =0 then cast(C.ID as  varchar(2)) 
        else cast(C.ParentID as varchar(2)) + '.' + cast(C.Order as varchar(3)) 
      END as Path, 
      C.Order 
  from Categories as C
```

You Need to create Temp tables if you have multiple level hierarchy. and you need to update order so that we have a simpler query for the desired output.

Thanks